# Android: MainActivity is suddenly created again in different Activity without being called?

Tags: android, android-activity

I m facing a weird behaviour. I start a new `Activity B` from within my `MainActivity` with

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  //tried addFlags as well
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Suddenly (between 10-45seconds), suddenly the `MainActivity` is starting again, without any reason. In Logcat, I see that the `MainActivity` is being created again (not even resumed), and received the intent `android.intent.action.MAIN`

Even more weird is, if I start another `ActivityC`, in the same way, it's working fine and not jumping back to the MainActivity...

Anyone any ideas?

Logcat

```
05-21 15:35:13.897: D/dalvikvm(14312): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 6% free 18231K/19356K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
05-21 15:35:13.936: D/dalvikvm(14312): GC_CONCURRENT freed 17K, 6% free 18213K/19356K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 33ms
05-21 15:35:14.108: D/dalvikvm(14312): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 6% free 18235K/19356K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
05-21 15:35:14.123: I/dalvikvm-heap(14312): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.696MB for 10342416-byte allocation
05-21 15:35:14.155: D/dalvikvm(14312): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 28335K/29460K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
05-21 15:35:14.178: D/dalvikvm(14312): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 28334K/29460K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 28ms
05-21 15:35:14.780: I/Choreographer(14312): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-21 15:35:23.623: D/dalvikvm(14312): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5879K, 18% free 28729K/34636K, paused 35ms, total 36ms
05-21 15:36:00.037: D/dalvikvm(14312): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6198K, 18% free 29094K/35320K, paused 7ms+14ms, total 92ms

//above, is the last result, before MainActivity is starting again

05-21 15:37:28.498: I/MainActivity(15078): onCreate() -> android.intent.action.MAIN
05-21 15:37:28.623: D/dalvikvm(15078): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 2% free 8901K/8996K, paused 44ms, total 45ms
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>      
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veeery strange.. In the end I found out, that I was using a `CustomTextView`, which is skewing the text to a large bitmap... I removed this due another solution, and now the `MainActivity` isn't starting anymore... Seems like my View was killed for some reason, but I didn't got any error in my Logcat... At least it's working now....

Answer (score 0):

remove launchmode or add it to all activity, u are always pushing mainactivity on top of other ones
edit: didnt see u did that ^^

Comment: if you go to C, do u also use Flags?

Comment: yes, it s the same call than starting ActivityB. That's why I'm confused... Every Activity has launchMode set to singleTop by the way..